How do I run an exectuable file with the GTK 4 library included?
I can save and compile C++ code with the library included in it via 64-bit MSYS2.
The issue is that I am incapable of running this executable. Here's the code I am attempting to run and experiment with to try and get used to the library:
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void on_activate(GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data) {
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GTK 4 Example");
    gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(window));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    app = gtk_application_new("com.example.GtkApplication", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(on_activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(app);

    return status;
}


Attempting to run this results in getting 3 consecutive system error popups about missing DLLs: libgobject-2.0-0.dll, libgio-2.0-0.dll, libgtk-4-1.dll.
I have downloaded the library via MSYS a while ago and I think it had some notes/warnings show up in the terminal.

The linked question should answer this. If not, please tell.

Did you use pacman to install this package: https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gtk4?repo=ucrt64 are you running from a msys terminal so that the dlls installed in msys are in a folder of the PATH environment variable?
